# Where can I find a list of my own questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Where can I find a list of my own questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3944171/nick-w?tab=questions

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3944171/nick-w?tab=questions

Comment: Or search `user:me is:question`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here:**

**https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=questions**

---

(You need to be logged in for this link to work, and it will take you to a list of your questions. If you're not logged in, or want to share your list of questions with others, you can also use a standard link with a userid, like [/users/3944171/](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944171/nick-w?tab=questions), which you can get to by clicking your profile image / link in the top bar)

Comment: Ah the image link is what I was looking for.